# Oracle circle distance search: missing results

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g

EDIT: (If u want see the old problematic, see at the bottom of this question)

With your helps i modified my statement:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
          SELECT 
                dest.ZC_ZIP, 
                dest.ZC_LOCATION_NAME,
                ACOS(
                    SIN(RADIANS(src.ZC_LAT)) * SIN(RADIANS(dest.ZC_LAT)) 
                    + COS(RADIANS(src.ZC_LAT)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.ZC_LAT))
                    * COS(RADIANS(src.ZC_LON) - RADIANS(dest.ZC_LON))
                    ) * 6371 AS DISTANCE
          FROM USER.ZC_COORDINATES dest
          CROSS JOIN USER.ZC_COORDINATES src
          WHERE src.ZC_ID = 
                (SELECT 
                        ZC_ID
                        FROM USER.ZC_COORDINATES
                        WHERE ZC_ZIP = '64289'
                        GROUP BY ZC_ID
                )
                AND
                (dest.ZC_ID <> src.ZC_ID OR dest.ZC_ID = src.ZC_ID)
      )
  HAVING DISTANCE <= 25 /* km */
  ORDER BY DISTANCE;
```

After this i get the error: "Radians" are invalid identifier.

Reason: Oracle doenst implements that function (MySQL does!).

So i search and found this Code and use it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_distance(pLat1 NUMBER, pLon1 NUMBER, pLat2 NUMBER, pLon2 NUMBER)
 RETURN NUMBER IS

-- r is the spherical radius of earth in Kilometers 
cSpherRad CONSTANT NUMBER := 6371;

-- The spherical radius of earth in miles is 3956
a        NUMBER;
vLat     NUMBER;
vLat1Rad NUMBER;
vLat2Rad NUMBER;
vLon     NUMBER;
vLon1Rad NUMBER;
vLon2Rad NUMBER;

BEGIN
  /*
  Most computers require the arguments of trigonometric functions to be
  expressed in radians. To convert lon1, lat1 and lon2,lat2 from
  degrees,minutes, seconds to radians, first convert them to decimal
  degrees. To convert decimal degrees to radians, multiply the number
  of degrees by pi/180 = 0.017453293 radians/degrees.
  */

  vLat1Rad := pLat1 * 0.017453293;
  vLat2Rad := pLat2 * 0.017453293;
  vLon1Rad := pLon1 * 0.017453293;
  vLon2Rad := pLon2 * 0.017453293;

  vLon := vLon2Rad - vLon1Rad;
  vLat := vLat2Rad - vLat1Rad;

  a := POWER(SIN(vLat/2),2) + COS(vLat1Rad) * COS(vLat2Rad) * POWER(SIN(vLon/2),2);

  /*
  The intermediate result c is the great circle distance in radians.
  Inverse trigonometric functions return results expressed in radians.
  To express c in decimal degrees, multiply the number of radians by
   180/pi = 57.295780 degrees/radian.
  The great circle distance d will be in the same units as r.
  */

  RETURN ROUND(cSpherRad * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a), SQRT(1-a)),1);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 999;
END calc_distance;
/
```

Successfully compilation.

Now the correct modification without group by errors:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
          SELECT 
                dest.ZC_ZIP AS ZIP, 
                dest.ZC_LOCATION_NAME AS LOCNAME,
                calc_distance(src.ZC_LAT, src.ZC_LON, dest.ZC_LAT, dest.ZC_LON) AS DISTANCE
          FROM BASE.ZC_COORDINATES dest
          CROSS JOIN BASE.ZC_COORDINATES src
          WHERE src.ZC_ID = 
                (SELECT 
                        ZC_ID
                        FROM BASE.ZC_COORDINATES
                        WHERE ZC_ZIP = '64289'
                        GROUP BY ZC_ID
                )
                AND
                (dest.ZC_ID <> src.ZC_ID OR dest.ZC_ID = src.ZC_ID)
      )
  HAVING DISTANCE <= 25 /* km */
  GROUP BY ZIP, LOCNAME, DISTANCE;
  --ORDER BY DISTANCE;
```

Whats the problem now?

Ok, on my old locals MySQL system i get these sql results (correct solution):

```
zc_zip  zc_location_name  distance     
64291   Darmstadt         0 
64297   Darmstadt         0 
64289   Darmstadt         0 
64283   Darmstadt         0 
64285   Darmstadt         0 
64295   Darmstadt         0 
64293   Darmstadt         0 
64287   Darmstadt         0 
64347   Griesheim, Hessen 5.385545333978872 
64331   Weiterstadt       5.671376373674798 
64367   M├╝hltal, Hessen  6.992565870106159 
64319   Pfungstadt        7.7621346384241585 
64380   Ro├ƒdorf bei Darmstadt 8.134881711148836 
64372   Ober-Ramstadt     8.421977582053422 
64390   Erzhausen, Hessen 9.419234655429722 
64572   B├╝ttelborn       9.739076077060767 
64409   Messel            9.962635340560048 
63329   Egelsbach, Hessen 11.274247321555363 
64342   Seeheim-Jugenheim 11.743554066395413 
64560   Riedstadt         12.135040456984065 
64404   Bickenbach        12.597317271640899 
64521   Gro├ƒ-Gerau       12.637599535794854 
64397   Modautal          13.260629389533909 
64846   Gro├ƒ-Zimmern     13.270265030251164 
63225   Langen (Hessen)   13.745513110307494
```

Thats i get from the oracle system:

```
ZIP     LOCNAME     DISTANCE
64293   Darmstadt   0
64283   Darmstadt   0
64295   Darmstadt   0
64285   Darmstadt   0
64297   Darmstadt   0
64287   Darmstadt   0
64289   Darmstadt   0
64291   Darmstadt   0
```

You see, some reults are missing.
I think the problem is the "GROUP BY" line in the oracle statement, which are needed.
So i cant delete this line. But how i can get my other results? I'm realy confused :(

---

(Old problematic)

At the moment i program a circle zip search for my employee.
My tool works under construction on my MySQL Database (local).

Now i migrate my OpenGeoDB into our oracle database (successfully) and want run my sql statement which works perfectly on my local MySQL database.

The full error message:

```
ORA-00904: "DISTANCE": invalid indentifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error in line: 20 col: 7
```

My SQL Statement:

```
SELECT 
    dest.zc_zip, 
    dest.zc_location_name,
    ACOS(
        SIN(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat)) 
        + COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat))
        * COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lon) - RADIANS(dest.zc_lon))
    ) * 6371 as distance
FROM USER.ZC_COORDINATES dest
CROSS JOIN USER.ZC_COORDINATES src
WHERE src.zc_id =
    (
    SELECT zc_id
    FROM USER.zip_coordinates
    WHERE zc_zip = '64289' /* Platzhalter fuer PLZ */
    GROUP BY zc_zip
    )

AND (dest.zc_id <> src.zc_id OR dest.zc_id = src.zc_id)
HAVING distance <= 25 /* km */
ORDER BY distance;
```

What I do to solve this problem?:
I switch the word "distance" with the full math calc, but after this, Oracle call invalid identifier "Radians"

Thats my problem because I dont know how I can solve this problem.

Have someone any ideas to solve that problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my last answer and solution for this question.
And sorry for the later answer. To much business.

A big thanks to [@Bob Jarvis](https://stackoverflow.com/u/213136/) and [@Ollie Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/u/205608) for their help and experience.

What are the problems?

- The different between MySQL and Oracle - Statements
- Migration problem with float numbers from MySQL to Oracle with "Oracle SQL Developer"
- Not existing function radians on Oracle

Solutions:

**Float number migration:**

To fix that problem I do that:

Use phpMyAdmin (PMA)
1. SQL File Select
2. Only data export, no structure or something
3. 1 line for 1 data set
4. Import into existing table on oracle serv

**Missing radiant function:**

Use this following statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RADIANS(nDEGREES IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
  BEGIN
  RETURN nDegrees / 57.29577951;
 END RADIANS;
 /
```

**SQL-Statement (MySQL one):**

```
SELECT 
    dest.zc_zip, 
    dest.zc_location_name,
    ROUND(ACOS(
        SIN(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat)) 
        + COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat))
        * COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lon) - RADIANS(dest.zc_lon))
    ) * 6371,
  1) as distance
FROM zip_coordinates dest
CROSS JOIN zip_coordinates src
WHERE src.zc_id =
    (
    SELECT zc_id
    FROM zip_coordinates
    WHERE zc_zip = '/zip/' /* placeholder for zip */
    GROUP BY zc_zip
    )
AND dest.zc_lat >= src.zc_lat -((/circle/-0.5)/111.045)
AND dest.zc_lat <= src.zc_lat +((/circle/-0.5)/111.045)
AND dest.zc_lon >= src.zc_lon -((/circle/-0.5)/(111.045 * COS(RADIANS(src.ZC_LAT))))
AND dest.zc_lon <= src.zc_lon +((/circle/-0.5)/(111.045 * COS(RADIANS(src.ZC_LAT))))
HAVING distance <= (/circle/-0.5) /* km */ /* placeholder for radius */
ORDER BY distance, dest.zc_zip;
```

**SQL-Statement (Oracle one):**

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
          SELECT 
                dest.ZC_ZIP AS ZIP, 
                dest.ZC_LOCATION_NAME AS LOCNAME,
                ROUND(
                 (6371* ACOS(
                      COS(RADIANS(dest.ZC_LAT))
                      * COS(RADIANS(src.ZC_LAT))
                      * COS(RADIANS(src.ZC_LON) - RADIANS(dest.ZC_LON))
                      + SIN(RADIANS(dest.ZC_LAT))
                      * SIN(RADIANS(src.ZC_LAT))
                      )
                 ), 1
                ) AS DISTANCE
          FROM ORACLE_USER.ZC_COORDINATES dest
          CROSS JOIN ORACLE_USER.ZC_COORDINATES src
          WHERE src.ZC_ID = 
                (SELECT 
                        ZC_ID
                        FROM ORACLE_USER.ZC_COORDINATES
                        WHERE ZC_ZIP = '/zip/'
                        GROUP BY ZC_ID
                )
                AND dest.ZC_LAT >= src.ZC_LAT -((/circle/-0.5)/111.045)
                AND dest.ZC_LAT <= src.ZC_LAT +((/circle/-0.5)/111.045)
                AND dest.ZC_LON >= src.ZC_LON -((/circle/-0.5)/(111.045 * COS(RADIANS(src.ZC_LAT))))
                AND dest.ZC_LON <= src.ZC_LON +((/circle/-0.5)/(111.045 * COS(RADIANS(src.ZC_LAT))))
      )
  HAVING DISTANCE <= (/circle/-0.5) /* km */ 
  GROUP BY ZIP, LOCNAME, DISTANCE
  ORDER BY DISTANCE;
```

Comment: For Oracle one, in version 11.1 was added the function calc_distance [link](http://psoug.org/reference/functions.html), useful to calculate accurately the distance.

Comment: Remember that the conversion const from distance to radians varies with latitude [link](http://www.longitudestore.com/how-big-is-one-gps-degree.html). I used an avg value of earth radius, more accurate:
`AND dest.ZC_LAT >= src.ZC_LAT - ((circle / 6371.4) * (180 / 3.1415926)) -- use pi() function if available
AND dest.ZC_LAT <= src.ZC_LAT + ((circle / 6371.4) * (180 / 3.1415926))
AND dest.ZC_LON >= src.ZC_LON - ((circle / 6371.4) * (180 / 3.1415926) / cos(src.ZC_LAT * 3.1415926/180))
AND dest.ZC_LON <= src.ZC_LON + ((circle / 6371.4) * (180 / 3.1415926) / cos(src.ZC_LAT * 3.1415926/180))`

Comment: thx @fl4l . if i find more time, i edit my solution with your notes. thanks for  your advice. n2m

Answer (score 0):

Oracle won't let you use a column computed in the SELECT list in a following ORDER BY. The following is a reasonable workaround:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT dest.ZC_ZIP, 
               dest.ZC_LOCATION_NAME,
               ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(src.ZC_LAT)) * SIN(RADIANS(dest.ZC_LAT)) 
                    + COS(RADIANS(src.ZC_LAT)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.ZC_LAT))
                    * COS(RADIANS(src.ZC_LON) - RADIANS(dest.ZC_LON))
                    ) * 6371 AS DISTANCE
          FROM USER.ZC_COORDINATES dest
          CROSS JOIN USER.ZC_COORDINATES src
          WHERE src.ZC_ID = (SELECT ZC_ID
                               FROM USER.ZIP_COORDINATES
                               WHERE ZC_ZIP = '64289'
                               GROUP BY ZC_ZIP) AND
                (dest.ZC_ID <> src.ZC_ID OR
                 dest.ZC_ID = src.ZC_ID))
  HAVING DISTANCE <= 25 /* km */
  ORDER BY DISTANCE;
```

Oracle also doesn't provide a function for converting degrees to radians but it's easy enough to add your own:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RADIANS(nDegrees IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
BEGIN
  -- radians = degrees / (180 / pi)
  -- RETURN nDegrees / (180 / ACOS(-1));  -- but 180/pi is a constant, so...
  RETURN nDegrees / 57.29577951308232087679815481410517033235;
END RADIANS;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
Now the problem is, the oracle database calls me he dont know the function Radians, called as "invalid identifier. I search for any solution, perhaps i find something, if not, i shout :D

Comment: Added RADIANS function. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i solved that problem too. But i have a new one, that u can see on the 1st entry.

Comment: I found the misstake, the migration was not 100% correct. The float numbers in long and lang columns are false. The import delete the points. I search a solution to fix it and if than it works, i close that question with an answer.

Comment: Prblem is solved, i tried to write the answer, but to make a bigger answer combine bullet list and sql code doenst work.